# Can I create a GIF that loops only a subset of frames?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

I am creating a banner using Photoshop CC 2015.
How can I make only two frames loop forever and the reset happens only once?

My frames from 1 to 30 brings content to the picture, it takes like 1 second, then I want to beep only one layer on and off.

please Help me with that if there is an alternative way explain it.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, that level of control is beyond the capabilities of the GIF format. Some searching on the subject brings up some dusty forum threads that support that notion [[1](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-10185.html), [2](https://forums.adobe.com/message/2338336#2338336)].

If this is intended for web, I would suggest using JavaScript to implement the animation flow that you require.